# Webconnex Ticket Details API

Tags: android

I want to develop an app like this. Is there an API for this?
http://ipclineapro.com/ticketscan/

Comment: What exactly is the problem you've encountered?

Comment: I just wanna make an am almost same as the one shown here. but wer can i get the data from? the barcode provides only the TicketID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TicketScan app is made specifically for the Webconnex platform (i.e someone buys tickets on Webconnex). So it isn't intended for other platforms, which is why it only provides a ticket number.

We do not, as of yet, have an Android app. When we first created TicketScan it only supported the Linea Pro (iPod accessory, now also for iPhone), but we later added support for QRCodes for the camera.

If you are wanting to make an Android app that works with our platform, we do have an internal REST based service the app uses. This service isn't documented, and we don't intend to release it publicly in its current form, partly because it may be changed in the near future.

Currently we are working on a revamp of our platform, which will have a slew of API's available.

Answer (score 0):

I recieved the reply to my mail from Webconnex. They said that there is no API open for us to use.